# NewRelic causing build errors

Tags: android, build, newrelic

After adding the NewRelic sdk to my android project, every time i try to build for release, i get this really long warning/error on the gradle console which also impacts build time; the project now takes twice as long to build.

```
27t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.b.v) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.b.x) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.c.b) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.c.c) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.c.d) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.c.e) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.c.k) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(c.a.a.a.a.d.e) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
```

I made sure to include newrelic in my proguard file and expected such warnings to be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proguard config should look like:

> -keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
>
> -dontwarn com.newrelic.**
>
> -keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!!