# Error in gradle build after updating Android Studio with log4j

Tags: android, android-studio, build, dependencies, build.gradle

I do get these errors after i updated Android Studio and the SDK:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$4) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$5) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$6) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$7) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.Main$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.MyTableModel$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.util.LogFileParser$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LF5SwingUtils$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$10) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$11) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$12) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$13) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$14) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$15) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$16) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$17) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$18) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$19) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$20) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$21) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$22) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$23) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$24) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$25) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$26) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$27) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$28) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
```

Installed SDK:

All including rev. 25.1.2

Android Studio:

Android Studio 2.0
Build #AI-143.2739321, built on April 5, 2016
JRE: 1.7.0_80-b15 amd64

The build.gradle file of the project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

signingConfigs {
    mulco {
        storeFile file("somePath")
        storePassword "..."
        keyAlias "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

def versionPropertiesFile = file('version.properties')
if (versionPropertiesFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropertiesFile))
    def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1
    versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
    println('count version up ' + code.toString())
    versionProps.store(versionPropertiesFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.mulco
        applicationId "com.test.mulcoandroid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode code
        versionName "1.03.01"
    }
} else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.mulco
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.mulco
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile project(':iCommonLibrary')
    compile project(':mulcobluetooth')
    compile project(':iScannerLibrary')
    compile project(':iPictureLibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
}
```

and of the dependant iCommonLibrary:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j:1.0.3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.1'
}
```

build.gradle of iPictureLibrary:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    compile project(':iCommonLibrary')
}
```

build.gradle of iScannerLibrary:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:android-core:3.2.1'
    compile files('libs/GrabbaSDK/Grabba driver for android v1.122.jar')
    compile project(':iCommonLibrary')
}
```

build.gradle file of mulcobluetooth:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

defaultConfig
{
    multiDexEnabled true
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
}
```

**I hope i provided any important information**

If someone does know anything ... please help me! I cannot find anything in this "NEULAND"

Sorry for the long question... Thanks for anyone who has made it up to here.

**EDIT:**

I updated the dependencies to:

```
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21'
```

But nothing has changed. I still have about 500 build errors .... I deleted mindpipe as reference an coded it by myself ... Nothing happened!

**EDIT:**

Opened a ticket:  Issue 206867

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206867

**EDIT:**

After uninstall Android Studio 2.0 and install 1.5.1 again I get the following warning:

Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Sources\iRecyApps\iRecyMulco-1.0.1iOS\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

So the gradle version was updated by 2...

I informed myself about the current gradle version and it's 2.12

I downloaded both and tried this:

You need to change File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home path

On Mac OS, change the path in Android Studio > Preferences > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home

Or set Use default gradle wrapper and edit Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties files field distributionUrl like this

according to:

["Gradle Version 2.10 is required." Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error)

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

Still nothing

Comment: I get the same boring error. Tried to recompile my external jars from source with jdk7. No luck so far.

Comment: Are you searching for a way to run the app even with this errors? Normally this errors are not relevant and if you disable instant run, the app will compile and run fine... With instant run enabled, I could not get my app working yet though...

Comment: I also get these errors. 325 in my case. If I hit debug the app starts and also instant run seems to work. Disabling it did not hide/solve the errors.

Comment: Have you found a real solution?  I'm stuck

Comment: No not yet... I was not able ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add this line to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

---

This error may happen almost all classes which has InnerClasses, I think.
(like support.v4 etc) for me.

---

I've tested on 
Android studio 2.2
(Not tested log4j. Tested support.v4 etc.)

**build.gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
...
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
}
```

---

`getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')`  also works.

Comment: where is proguard-rules.pro?? I am facing the same issue but can't able to find this file.

Comment: @Furqan Under "Gradle Scripts" in project view. File path is (project)/app/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: Related Issue 215748: AGPBI reports errors instead of warnings See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215748 (Linked from Issue 206867 #8).

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this same error. It was driving me crazy because the error count was >1K. And I was getting these errors on release build with proguard enabled.

After doing some digging I found that adding `-keepattributes EnclosingMethod` in your `proguard-rules.pro` file all these error will be gone.

**Source**: [Thread](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/issues/285) and [Issue #294](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/pull/294) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgrading all com.android.support dependencies to 23.1.1 in Gradle configuration.

Comment: Isn't this upgrading ... ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem at hand right now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I met this error when I made `Instant Run` enable,but after disable `Instant Run`,the error was disappeared.[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Write this code snippet in proguard-rules.pro in your project.**

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

By writing above snippet to proguard-rules.pro file, the proguard rules actually changes how the classes are obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, start a new Android studio project
copy and paste gradle-wrapper.properties and build.gradle (Project: "Project Name") in your old project that had the error - in order to upgrade your gradle

Also add this in your proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Update your build.gradle (Module:app) as follows

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
```

Comment: I am not in that project anymore. I cannot test it :-(