# Project error run in real device

Tags: android, ftp

When i run my project in emulator, it works. But, I got this error when i try to run the program in samsung galaxy note. Please help me to solve this problem. I'm using ftp external library . i have been struggle with this error. Please help me

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

This is my manifest

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amobi.newlomapodfix"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':captcha')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}
```

For the FTP i'm using this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592864/error-in-gradle-build-after-updating-android-studio-with-log4j) solutions?

Comment: yes still failed, session app: error instaling APK @DanielK

Comment: how did you resolve the issues ?