# Android Studio Gradle Error after using @org.parceler.Parcel

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After using in two of my app classes the following line: @org.parceler.Parcel, I'm getting this Gradle Build Error:

> warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (org.parceler.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap$1)  that doesn't come
>   with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably
>   produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file
>   format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from
>   source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any
>   "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is
>   that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate
>   that it is *not* an inner class.

In spite of it, the app compiles and runs succesfully. However this error annoys me because I don't know if it will cause app crashes.

My build.graddle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 26
        versionName "2.0.18"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("omitted")
            storePassword "omitted"
            keyAlias "omitted"
            keyPassword "omitted"

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.0'
    // [START gms_compile]
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    // [END gms_compile]
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.3'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.3'
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed but I'm getting the exact same error message.

Comment: Ok, can you revert to old api level 23, abd once check error id still coming or not

Comment: I just started reverting but it became very messy since I have lots of calls to new API inside my source-code.

Comment: First you revert all and then sync n which class is missing or error is came tell me

Answer (score 0):

according to this issue: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/19

the answer is:

> you're running into the dex method limit. Unrelated to this library.

It seems to you should enable `multidex` in your app to hide this warning.

This might be helpful: [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Comment: I've enabled multidex by adding "multiDexEnabled true" to build.gradle, however the Gradle Error still appears. Do you think such build error would cause my app to crash for the final users? My tests are OK so far.

Comment: are you sure that you'd enabled Multidexing properly. Did you may have forgotten about `MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());` in class where you initialize Parceler. If I were you, I would open new issue on Parceler site and check answers. No, I don't think that it would crahs on users phones.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592864/error-in-gradle-build-after-updating-android-studio-with-log4j - the answer is that this kind of problem is safe and good to ignore. You can try update your support libraries to hide this issue