# I am getting following error while build my signed apk in my app

Tags: android, android-build, android-studio-2.2, android-buildconfig

I am getting following error in my console, please help me, is there any problem in publishing to app store.(i apologize for my English & this is my first app using android studio)
[MoreInfo](http://fusioniprojects.com/Error_apk.txt)

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(android.support.v4.app.ab) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a...
```

Comment: This solution might help.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592864/error-in-gradle-build-after-updating-android-studio-with-log4j>

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines to the ProGuard config (app/proguard-rules.pro)

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have to false from my gradle " minifyEnabled false" from true +1 for your partial help