# Getting "EnclosingMethod" errors on building in Android Studio 2

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I am getting below build errors when I am running the app in Android Studio 2. These errors were not there when I was using earlier version of Android Studio.

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.squareup.haha.guava.base.Joiner$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.squareup.haha.guava.collect.Iterables$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.squareup.haha.guava.collect.Iterables$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

What are these errors and how to resolve them? Also, the apk is building fine and the app also runs perfectly.

Comment: did u try clean->rebuild

Comment: @Lokanath yes, I tried that already.

Comment: Got the solution from here while searching about the problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36523016/1263362

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large number of errors during Gradle build after upgrading to Android Studio 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522313/large-number-of-errors-during-gradle-build-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-0)

Answer (score 30):

## Update 2016/09/19

This is fixed in LeakCanary 1.4, so simply upgrading should fix it without needing to mess with an alternate version of `haha`.

```
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4'
```

## Previously

These warnings are caused by `haha:2.0.2`, which is a dependency of `leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2`.

It's fixed in `haha:2.0.3`, so you can fix it by explicitly using the newer version in your dependencies. Add this line for each flavor where you are adding a `leakcanary` dependency. You don't need to add it for `leakcanary-android-no-op`, since it has no dependencies.

```
debugCompile 'com.squareup.haha:haha:2.0.3'
```

Comment: It is the simplest way to get rid of this annoying warning. Thank you

Answer (score 15):

Adding

`-keepattributes EnclosingMethod`

to proguard's configuration file (in my case, `proguard.cfg`) seems to have fixed this.

Comment: Debug builds don't usually build w/proguard (because it takes so long, so most configs don't have it on).. but I suppose it should...

Answer (score 5):

I was getting same error. It seems there was some problem with leakcanary (in my case). I tried following changes in proguard file.

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.guava.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.perflib.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.trove.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.leakcanary.**
-keep class com.squareup.haha.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.leakcanary.** { *; }

# Marshmallow removed Notification.setLatestEventInfo()
-dontwarn android.app.Notification
```

I am not getting those issue anymore. Here is the [link](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/leakcanary-android/consumer-proguard-rules.pro)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by adding following dependency to my build.gradle:

testCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2"

here is link:https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/491