# Android project no longer compiles when api dependency is compiled with JDK 21

Tags: java, android, java-21

I am using an api written in Java in an Android project. This api is restricted to Java 8 features.
Until recently, this worked fine. The api was compiled using OpenJDK 17 so far.
Now, the project releasing the api is upgrading to Java 21, thus the api, too, is compiled using OpenJDK 21.
Without any code changes, this suddenly leads to compilation errors in my android project.
I am unsing Gradle 7.5 and the Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2.

The following error pops up during the build process:

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"String.length()\" because \"<parameter1>\" is null","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\c.dargel\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\6241a5d0420a8882bad7c16a963\\transformed\\jetified-test-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
```

After trying to find some information about the error itself, I could not find anything useful, sadly.
I tried changing the compile JDK in Android Studio to different versions, to no avail.

Comment: Does this help? See first answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522313/large-number-of-errors-during-gradle-build-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-0

Comment: It did not, as it seems to be a combination of different factors.